# In ruby, how to do a DES encryption with PKCS5 padding

Tags: python, ruby, openssl, 3des

I am trying to convert some Python code into Ruby. Here is a snippet of the Python code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pyDes
import base64
des3Key = '1234567887654321'
iv = des3Key[0:8]
data = r'abc'
k = pyDes.triple_des(des3Key,pyDes.CBC,iv,pad=None,padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt(data)
print base64.b64encode(d)
#q8qN6El3X8A=
```

My Ruby code:

```
require 'digest'
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

data = 'abc'

key = '1234567887654321'
iv = key[0..7]
# cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3')
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC') # or any other algorithm?

cipher.encrypt
cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(key, iv)
output = cipher.update(data)
output << cipher.final
p Base64.encode64(output).gsub(/\n/, "")
# y7TPhjBQO78=
```

**The ruby result not equal python's** .Which algorithm should I choose?

Comment: A Triple DES should be 24 bytes long not 16 characters. Also, cryptographic keys should be indistinguishable from random noise which means that they cannot consist solely of digits or even alphanumerics. They should be randomly chosen may contain any possible byte value.

Comment: **Don't use Triple DES nowadays.** It only provides at best 112 bit of security even if you use the largest key size of 192 bit. If a shorter key size is used, then it only provides 56 or 57 bits of security. AES would be faster (processors have a special AES-NI instruction set) and even more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with 3DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: @ArtjomB. the ruby result not equal python's

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm calling an api of a third party system used DES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, don’t use `pkcs5_keyivgen`, this is an old and deprecated function for deriving a key and iv from a password. You need to set these directly on the `Cipher` object:

```
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
```

Second, in your Python code the key is 16 bytes, which means you are using *two key* (or keying option 2) triple DES. The Python code automatically determines which to use depending on the length of the key used. In the Ruby OpenSSL bindings you need to explicitly specify which to use. `des-ede3-cbc` is *three key* (or keying option 1). You need to use `des-ede-cbc` as the cipher name:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('des-ede-cbc')
```